# SQL query to find the friends in a table

Tags: sql, union

I have two tables, `Users` and `Friends`. The tables look like:

```
USERS
|  ID   |  Name   | 
|  1    |  Sam    | 
|  2    |  Harry  |         
|  3    |  Vivi   |
|  4    | sabrina |

FRIENDS
| UId   | FriendID| 
|  1    |    2    |    
|  2    |    3    |  
|  4    |    1    | 
|  5    |    4    | 
|  1    |    3    |
```

I need to find the names of all the friends for Sam. I tried doing the same using a **Union** in an SQL query, but I couldn't get the desired output. Can I possibly get the required output doing the same?

Comment: What is this FriendShip Flag? please add proper flag.

Comment: {Harry, Vivi, Sabrina} Next!

Comment: Have a look at [SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 6):

```
declare
@answer nvarchar(max)='{'
select @answer=@answer+u1.Name+',' from USERS u
inner join FRIENDS f on f.UId=u.ID
inner join USERS u1 on u1.ID=f.FriendID
where u.ID=<what ever you want> //1 or 2 or 3 or 4

set @answer=SUBSTRING(@answer,0,len(@answer)-1)+'}'
select @answer
```

Comment: Give Rate if it is useful for you.

Comment: i tried the query but it just returns the Name from just one colum but it is supposed to return {Harry, Vivi, Sabrina} instead of that , it returns just sabrina .

Comment: Now it returns the Following o/p:
`{Sabrina      ...`

Comment: how do i get 
`Harry
Vivi
Sabrina`
as the output since Those are Sam's friends ....

Comment: i am not getting, what mean sam's friend. can you enplane more

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.name from users
join friends f on users.id=f.uid
join users u on u.id=f.friendid
where users.name='Sam';
```

Comment: i tried the query but it just returns the Name from just one colum but it is supposed to return `{Harry, Vivi, Sabrina}` instead of that , it returns just `sabrina`

Comment: One name per row (with multiple rows, however), as SQL results should be. If you want to format it to different string - you should specify desired format in question and tell up what SQL system you using - because standard SQL don't have this functionality.